# Check if thread already exists in group conversation

Tags: mysql

I've a platform where users send messages. Group conversation is possible to.

My thread_members table:

```
id | user_id | thread_id 
------------------------- 
 1 |    1    |     1   
------------------------- 
 2 |    2    |     1  
------------------------- 
 3 |    1    |     2  
------------------------- 
 4 |    2    |     2  
------------------------- 
 5 |    3    |     2  
------------------------- 
 6 |    1    |     3  
------------------------- 
 7 |    3    |     3  
------------------------- 
 8 |    4    |     3
```

When i send a message, i want to check if this thread already exists.

Lets say: user_id '1' sends a message to user_id '2'

The result should be thread_id '1'

It should be a single query

### EDIT

Thanks to everyone but i think i got my answere:
I'm not getting any problems til now...

In PHP:

```
$senderId = $_POST['sender']; // integer
$receiverIds = $_POST['receivers']; // array

$query = "SELECT thread_members.*, COUNT(*) 
          FROM thread_members 
          JOIN (   
            SELECT *, COUNT(*)   
            FROM (     
              SELECT *     
              FROM thread_members     
              WHERE user_id = " . $senderId . " "; 

              foreach ($receiverIds as $receiverId) 
              {
                $query .= " OR user_id = " . $receiverId . " ";  
              }

              $query .= " ) AS thread_members 
            GROUP BY thread_id 
            HAVING COUNT(*) = " . (count($receiverIds) + 1) . "
            ORDER BY COUNT(*) 
          ) AS thread_members_copy ON thread_members.thread_id = thread_members_copy.thread_id 
          GROUP BY thread_members.thread_id 
          HAVING COUNT(*) = " . (count($receiverIds) + 1) . "
          ORDER BY COUNT(*) ";
```

`(count($receiverIds) + 1)` are all receivers + the sender

Answer (score 0):

You can do a self join and then check for records containing the two user id values:

```
SELECT t1.thread_id FROM
thread_members t1 INNER JOIN thread_members t2
ON t1.thread_id = t2.thread_id
WHERE t1.user_id = 1 AND t2.user_id = 2
```

Comment: @del4y According to your sample data, _both_ threads 1 and 2 have user 1 and 2 communicating with each other.  Am I missing something?  You should really try to use a simple query to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>{
        new Tuple<int,int,int>(1,1,1),
        new Tuple<int,int,int>(2,2,1),
        new Tuple<int,int,int>(3,1,2),
        new Tuple<int,int,int>(4,2,2),
        new Tuple<int,int,int>(5,3,2),
        new Tuple<int,int,int>(6,1,3),
        new Tuple<int,int,int>(7,3,3),
        new Tuple<int,int,int>(8,4,3),
    };

    var users = data.Select(x => x.Item2).Distinct();
    foreach(var user in users){
        var threads = data.Where(x => x.Item2 == user).Select(x => x.Item3);
        foreach(var thread in threads){
            var counterParties = data.Where(x => x.Item3 == thread && x.Item2 != user)
            .Select(x => x.Item2);
            foreach(var party in counterParties)
                Console.WriteLine("user {0} send thread {1} user {2}", user, thread, party);
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

`user 1 send thread 1 user 2
user 1 send thread 2 user 2
user 1 send thread 2 user 3
user 1 send thread 3 user 3
user 1 send thread 3 user 4
user 2 send thread 1 user 1
user 2 send thread 2 user 1
user 2 send thread 2 user 3
user 3 send thread 2 user 1
user 3 send thread 2 user 2
user 3 send thread 3 user 1
user 3 send thread 3 user 4
user 4 send thread 3 user 1
user 4 send thread 3 user 3`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but i want to make single query. My fault, i didn't mention it.